# C# DataGridView Columns Display Index: Does it change the column index?

Tags: c#, datagridview, indexing, multiple-columns

I have a DataGridView object, the columns of which I am re-arranging by assigning them particular values for their DisplayIndex properties like so:

```
grdMain.Columns["BarcodeNumber"].DisplayIndex = 0;
grdMain.Columns["Type"].DisplayIndex = 1;
grdMain.Columns["Title"].DisplayIndex = 2;
grdMain.Columns["ParentID"].DisplayIndex = 3;
```

I am re-arranging the columns this way ***after*** I have populated the DGV object.

My question is this:

If I start with, for example, the grdMain.Columns["BarcodeNumber"] column being being the fifth column in the grid (index of 4), and then re-assign that column's DisplayIndex property to be 0, which of the following will correctly access the value of the BarcodeColumn:

```
grdMain.Columns[0]
```

or

```
grdMain.Columns[4]
```

Does altering the DisplayIndex for a DGV column affect its actual index on the grid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewband.index%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The value of this property does not necessarily correspond to the current visual position of the band within the collection. For example, if the user reorders columns in a DataGridView at run time (assuming the AllowUserToOrderColumns property is set to true), the value of **the Index property of each column will not change**. Instead, the column DisplayIndex values change. Sorting rows, however, does change their Index values.

Answer (score 0):

I think it does though i'm not 100% sure as I would tend to use the column name

You would be better using the column name rather than the index unless you have a specific reason not to, this way you don't have to worry about the column index.